# Parsing JSON in an Azure Service Bus rule

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am trying to add a rule on a subscription on Azure service bus. The payload of the message looks like this:

```
{
  header: {
    // a bunch of data
  },
  body: {
    type: "payment",
    // a bunch of data
  }
}
```

Using New-AzureRMServiceBusRule to create a new rule, i get a 400 error when i try to add `"body.type = 'payment'"`. If I just use `"type = 'payment'"` everything is fine, but the standard library my client uses forces everything into its own envelope structure.

Is there a way to parse a JSON payload in a service bus rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Service Bus rules only operate on headers. If you'd like to evaluate things from the payload/body, you will have to promote those into custom/user headers.

An FYI, if you're filtering based on equality, [Correlation filters](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/asb-subs-with-correlation-filters) is much more efficient than [SQL filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-sql-filter).